# Is this Raleigh headset worn?

Tags: headset

I was wondering am I correct in saying this this headset race is worn and needs to be replaced.

It's off a BSA wayfarer bike. It has a 1 inch threaded steerer.

I read on Sheldon's website you can use a JIS headset if it's the bottom races but this is the threaded part that screws onto the steerer.

Can I still use the JIS headset ?

Its weird its just the one in the image thats worn. Everything else is as good as new.

[image]

Comment: If it's not a bearing race or a threaded area then it's not a problem.  Yours may have been manufactured that way, or it may have gotten scratches from installation on a fork tube with jagged top.

Comment: make that an answer i'll give u brownie points daniel.  Ok if it's not a problem then I wont fix it lol.

Comment: Just use a decent blob of marine grade grease, and enough ball bearings. Up to you if you use loose bearings or caged ones - theres no practical difference once assembled.